# What does the number inside the brackets mean in the output of whatis command in linux

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

For example,

```
[root@fedora ~]# whatis pwd
pwd (1p) - return working directory name
pwd (1) - print name of current/working directory
pwd [builtins] (1) - bash built-in commands, see bash(1)
pwd.h [pwd] (0p) - password structure
```

What are those 0p,1,1p? Sometimes, I also see the word rpm in the brackets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Man page sections.  You can disambiguate which manual section you want by typing

```
man 1 pwd
```

For instance, say you typed

```
allhats2:~> whatis crontab
crontab (5)          - tables for driving cron
crontab (1)          - maintain crontab files for individual users (V3)
```

And you wanted to see the entry about the structure of the tables, you could type

```
man 5 crontab
```